# Org-plot with gnuplot (searching for program: No such file or direcotry, aspell)

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I am trying to plot simple examples in org-mode by using gnuplot. But it keeps telling me
`"Searching for program: No such file or directory, aspell"`.

I installed gnuplot both to on emacs and on system wide. Also installed gnuplot-mode in emacs.

The table that I am trying to plot is:

```
#+PLOT: title:"Grades in Physics and Mathematics" ind:2 deps:(3 4) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]" set:"xlabel 'Student'" set:"ylabel 'grades'" set:"output './img/gnuplot-grades.png'" set:"terminal png size 600,500"
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
|   | Grades | Mathematics | Physics |
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
| # | Ben    |         9.2 |     9.9 |
| # | Tom    |         6.7 |     7.7 |
| # | Tim    |         7.5 |     6.7 |
| # | Dean   |         8.0 |     7.0 |
```

I am using org-mode 9.3.7 which came by default. Is the issue related with emacs/org-mode version?

B.R.

Comment: You must have enabled a spell checker that is configured to use `aspell`. Two choices: find out where and disable it, or install `aspell`.

Comment: Thank you. ```aspell``` problem is solved by installing it via os's package manager. But still cannot produce any plots. I checked the gnuplot version on both emacs and system which were different  and fixed that. Still,it does not produce any plots. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that:

- `gnuplot` is installed: just run it from the shell to make sure it's present and if so, just exit out of it (I have version 5 and that worked).
- [gnuplot-mode](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/gnuplot) is installed; checking e.g. with `C-h f gnuplot-mode RET` should be enough.
- make sure that there is a subdirectory `img` under the directory where the Org mode file lives: the options specify `set:"output './img/gnuplot-grades.png'"` but if the `img` directory does not exist, this will fail.

With all conditions satisfied, I was able to produce the output file.

If you still have trouble, check your `*Messages*` buffer for messages like this:

```
gnuplot-mode 0.6.0 (gnuplot 5.0) -- report bugs with "C-c C-u"
```

which shows that both `gnuplot-mode` and `gnuplot` are installed and what the versions are (my `gnuplot mode` is old: 0.7.0 is available).

If you see such messages, then there should also be  a buffer named`*gnuplot*` that `gnuplot-mode` creates and uses to send commands to the underlying `gnuplot` process. Switch to that buffer and see if any commands failed and what the errors are.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again. The problem was in saving settings.

Comment: On Windows, what solved it for me (after, of course, installing gnuplot for Windows and putting the binary in %PATH%) was downloading the latest versions of `gnuplot` and `gnuplot-mode` on MELPA.